# ContryCodePicker shows as a question mark in component tree

Tags: android

I'm trying to add `CountryCodePicker` in my android project, in component tree it is showing question mark at CCP and it's not working.

This is XML code which I am using right now

```
<com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
                android:id="@+id/ccp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:ccp_defaultNameCode="IN">
</com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker>
```

[image]